# Multiple root A records for Google Domains

Tags: google-domains, firebase

I am trying to set two A records for the root url in Google Domains as required by Firebase but it seems Google Domains doesn't allow duplicate rules

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a little + beside the ipv4 input field that allows you to add a second address to the same rule ‍♂️

For existing rules it only appears once you click Edit